# Rails 3.2 Security

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-models

In my rails app I have a User Model where I have an attribute: points

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :points
    has_many :answers
end
```

Is there a way to make the attribute updated only from specific controller actions?

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
   ....
   def create
      @user = current_user
      @answer = @user.answers.build(params[:answer])
      if @answer.save
        @user.points += 10  # <-- I want to make points updatable only from this action
        @user.save
      else
        ...
      end
     ... 
   end
```

Comment: You don't need `attr_accessible` if you use the setter directly as you do currently

Comment: If your goal here is to prevent mass assignment, `attr_accessible` is supposed to do this already; it does not lock down the actions you use, but it will prevent the score from being changed except when you directly assign it in a controller action.

Comment: That's incorrect, apneadiving: if `points` were accessible, a user could assign whatever value they wanted to their points on initial creation or update through mass assignment vulnerability.

Comment: @Veraticus you'd better reread the code shown here + what I wrote. I don't say you're wrong neither, my comment was a mere comment intended to give a different aspect of the issue. Obviously, in the example, the setter will work with or without `attr_accessible`

Comment: @apneadiving Guh... for some reason I was reading `attr_protected` instead of `attr_accessible`. You're right, it should be protected, and he shouldn't use `attr_accessible`.